# Is there a way to us CKS Dev Tools to find undisposed of objects?

Tags: visual-studio, cksdev

I thought I had used CKS Dev tools to display warnings about undisposed of objects in Visual Studio in the past, but we just stood up a new server and I can't seem to find a way to do it.  Can it be done?  If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the [SharePoint Dispose Checker](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck) tool from Microsoft.